# Mean and Variance of Stationary AR(1) Model

Tags: autocorrelation, stationarity, autoregressive

Please consider the following stationary AR(1) model: $X_t =\alpha X_{t-1} + Z_t$ ; where $Z_t$ is a purely random process with mean zero and variance $\sigma_z^2$ and $X_0$ equals to zero.

I can derive the mean of the process by re-writing it as an infinite sum of a purely random process, using back substitution.

\begin{eqnarray}
X_{t}&=&\alpha X_{t-1}+Z_{t}\nonumber\\
&=&\alpha(\alpha X_{t-2}+Z_{t-1}) + Z_{t}\nonumber\\
&=& \alpha^{2}X_{t-2} + \alpha Z_{t-1} + Z_{t}\nonumber\\
&=& \alpha^{2}(\alpha X_{t-3}+Z_{t-2}) + \alpha Z_{t-1} + Z_{t}\nonumber\\
&=& \alpha^{3}X_{t-3}+\alpha^{2}Z_{t-2} + \alpha Z_{t-1} + Z_{t}\nonumber\\
&=&\vdots\nonumber\\
&=&\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\alpha^{j}Z_{t-j}\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

Then the mean is

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}[X_{t}]&=&\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\alpha^{j}Z_{t-j}\right]\nonumber\\
&=&\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\alpha^{j}\mathbb{E}[Z_{t-j}]\nonumber\\
&=&\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\alpha^{j}\times0\nonumber\\
&=&0\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

The variance is also calculated by writing $X_t$ as an infinite sum of a purely random process.

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathrm{Var}[X_{t}]&=&\mathrm{Var}\left[\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\alpha^{j}Z_{t-j}\right]\nonumber\\
&=&\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\mathrm{Var}[\alpha^{j}Z_{t-j}]\nonumber\\
&=&\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\alpha^{2j}\mathrm{Var}[Z_{t-j}]\nonumber\\
&=&\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\alpha^{2j}\times\sigma_{z}^{2}\nonumber\\
&=&\sigma_{z}^{2}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\alpha^{2j}\nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

Firstly, I hope there are no mistakes up until this point. Then, what happens to the mean and variance of $X_t$ when $Z_t$ is normally and identically distributed with a mean of zero and variance of let's say $1-\alpha^2$?

Also, in a model like $X_{j,t} = \alpha_j X_{j,t-1} + Z_{j,t}$, what happens to the mean and variance of $X_{j,t}$ when the variance of $Z_{j,t}$ is something like $1-\alpha_j^2$ with a mean of zero?

I hope someone can explain it. If you don't want to or don't have time to explain, please suggest me a book or an online source to check. I could not find any explanation on the internet or any book I have.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty standard variance result that you can find in a number of places on this site.  The remaining step for the variance is done using the formula for an [infinite geometric sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum).  Assuming that $|\alpha| < 1$ (a necessary condition for stationarity) we have:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{V}(X_t)
&= \sigma_z^2 \sum_{j=0}^\infty \alpha^{2j} \\[6pt]
&= \sigma_z^2 \sum_{j=0}^\infty (\alpha^2)^j \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\sigma_z^2}{1-\alpha^2}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

This gives you the general formula when the error terms in the model have a fixed variance $\sigma_z^2$.  (Results for particular values of the variance can then be obtained by substitution.)  For the case where the variance of $Z_j$ is not fixed the situation is more complicated, and you would need to do the derivation again from first principles.